# In my webpage it is showing results from id=3 and missing id 1,2

Tags: php, html, css

My code is below.

Since my items are many in numbers i showed on 12 items at a time but it is starting from item number 3 and skipping item 1, 2

```
  if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
  $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM item_table LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page"; 
  $rs_result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Unable to get results"); //run the query
  $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result) or die("Unable to get rows");
  <?php 
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result))
  {     
  ?>
      <form>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
          <div class="thumbnail" style="height:350px; background-color:black;transparent">
          <a href="/Bootstrap/display-item.php?id=<?php echo $row ['Item_Id']; ?>" ><img  src="<?php echo $row['image_path']?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title']?>"> </img></a> 
          <h3 style="color:white;" ><?php echo $row['title']?></h3>
          <p><?php// echo $row['s_des']?></p>
          </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      <div align="center">
        <?php 
  } //end of loop ?>
?>
```

Comment: what is the value of $num_rec_per_page?

Comment: `$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result) or die("Unable to get rows");` is retrieving and then discarding the first result

Comment: And stop using the old, deprecated MySQL interface, switch to MySQLi or PDO and learn to use prepared statements with bind variables

Comment: $num_rec_per_page=13;

Comment: @MarkBaker so how to make it correct :( i'm beginner in this

Comment: If you have to use the MySQL extension, then [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) tells you how many rows there are in the resultset